# PHP redirect within ifstatement

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if($_POST['profileName']!="") {
    $profileName = $_POST['profileName'];

    if (!($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE `user_settings` SET ProfileName=?,ProfileSetup=? WHERE Username=?")) || !is_object($stmt)) {
        die( "Error preparing: (" .$con->errno . ") " . $con->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('sis', $profileName, 1, $_SESSION['user']);
    if($stmt->execute()) { 
        echo '<div class="alert_successful alert_absolute_center">';
        echo 'Profile Name change Successful!';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert_unsuccessful alert_absolute_center">';
        echo 'Something went wrong... Try again!';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to redirect to different places depending on the result of the if statement... I have tried setting variables and then using a meta redirect, but of course that didn't work because it was looking for the variable before it was actually set...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `echo '<script>location="/test"</script>';`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) you may be able to set a `header` redirect:

```
if($stmt->execute())
    header('Location: your_page_success.php');
else
    header('Location: your_page_fail.php');
```

Otherwise the `header` call wont work if you have already started outputting data (e.g. with `echo`).

Comment: How would this help in my circumstance? The redirect has to go within the if statement?

Comment: As per your comment line, this answer is no appropriate for the OP's question since he **is** echoing HTML.

Comment: I'd make a habit of adding `exit()` after as well.

Comment: Yep, add `exit;` after the `header()` to prevent executing the rest of the script.

Comment: On its own it is not. It does **not** work with the OP's current code at all and makes no effort to suggest other solutions for the response messages.

Comment: @scrowler output buffering is a ini setting, which is not code reliant (although it can be).

Comment: Come on guys... stop it with the shortcuts. Take a step back, is output buffering really the right solution for what he's trying to do?  OP is clearly a inexperienced developer trying to learn. Let's give him some good practices instead of just links to PHP docs.

Comment: If you want to write bad code, then don't put `exit()` after the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting is [easy](http://davidwalsh.name/php-redirect-function). It's your approach that needs some work.

Essentially, here's what you want to do:

1. Go somewhere (your current script)
2. Figure out what you want to do with what you have (your current logic)
3. Show the user some feedback about what you did is step #2
   *Which may or may not be redirecting the user to a different location*

First of all, I would suggest redirecting the user, even if it's to the same page. This will prevent the, "Would you like to submit this form again?" type alerts the user would get if they were to refresh the page after they had submitted a form.

The best way to [redirect](http://davidwalsh.name/php-redirect-function) is using PHP's [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. Just make sure that nothing is printed to the page before the you execute this command. Also, always follow it by an `exit();`.

Now what about the user's feedback message? There are a number of ways you can handle this; here's a couple:

1. Have a predefined and indexed list of messages (whether it's hard-coded, in a database, or in a config file somewhere. When you redirect, add the index in the URL as a parameter, something like `http://redirecttohere.com/?msg=badpwd`. You can now take this parameter and retrieve and display the appropriate message.
2. ***PREFERED*** Store your message in a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable, redirect, retrieve message from session, display message, destroy said session variable. Check out [this guy's solution](http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/); use it and/or check out his source code and figure out how he did it.